# Spring Boot custom validation problem in Java app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, exception

I am trying to throw exception while uploading file if the file format is not csv type. Here is my implementation (some parts are omitted for clarity):

***ValidFile:***

```
@Documented
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {FileValidator.class})
public @interface ValidFile {
    //...
}
```

***FileValidator:***

```
public class FileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidFile, MultipartFile> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MultipartFile multipartFile, 
                           ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

***ValidationErrorResponse:***

```
public class ValidationErrorResponse {

    // have "fieldName" and "response" data
}
```

***ErrorHandlingControllerAdvice:***

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ErrorHandlingControllerAdvice {

    //I tried to use something like that >>>

    @ExceptionHandler(NotValidFormatException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    @ResponseBody
    ValidationErrorResponse onNotValidFormatException(NotValidFormatException e) {
        //...
    }
}
```

And, as there is not a file field in db, I validated uploaded file parameter as shown below (I want to validate on Controller):

***Controller:***

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(
                @Valid @ValidFile @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
                throws Exception {
            employeeService.create(file);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseMessage("File uploaded.));
    }
```

I also tried to use `@Validated`, `@RequestPart("file")` as parameter, but does not make any sense.

When I try to upload an invalid type (pdf) and trace the exception, I see "*Failed to parse csv file: (line 322) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter*" error. So, how can I catch the exception in my `onNotValidFormatException` method?

Comment: Does anybody else have ever used custom validation in Spring Boot

Comment: Why dont you set consumes atrribute of requestmapping to text/csv. You can only get csv file. Later you can handle spring exception

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez Why don't you post an example?